# $f(X)=X^{16}-X \in \mathbb F_2 [X]$ ,order of primitive roots, polynomial of minimal degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials, primitive-roots

Given is the polynomial $f(X)=X^{16}-X \in \mathbb F_2 [X]$.

It factorizes into $f(X)=X(X+1)q(X)$, where $q(X)=X^{14}+X^{13}+\dots +X+1$.

Now, let $\alpha$ be a primitive root of $\mathbb F_{16}$ and define $\beta := \alpha ^3$.

Now the first question is, what are the orders of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb F_{16}^*$.

$\mathbb F_{16}^*$ is the group of units. Since $\alpha$ is a primitive root, it has to generate $\mathbb F_{16}^*$ and so the order of $\alpha$ is $\varphi(16)=\varphi(2^4)=(2-1)2^{4-1}=8$. Is this right? And what does this give to me for the order of $\beta$?

The second question is: What is the lowest degree of a nontrivial polynomial in $\mathbb F_2 [X]$, which has the root $\beta$. Here I don't know, hoe to go on. I thought about, that if a polynomial has $\beta$ as a root, then it has also the roots $\beta^2,\beta^3,\dots$, but I don't know wheteher this is helpful.

Comment: The first part is wrong. The group $\mathbb{F}_{16}^\ast$ is just $\mathbb{F}_{16} \backslash \{0\}$ as a set and so it has order $15$. You might be confusing this with the group $U(16)$ of units modulo $16$.

Comment: By using my script form the lecture we mean the group of units. Im sure. What would be the answer then?

Comment: The group of units modulo $16$ denoted $U(16)$ consists of the invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$, i.e the equivalence classes of integers that are relatively prime to $16$. The unit group $\mathbb{F}_{16}^\ast$ consists of the invertible elements in $\mathbb{F}_{16}$, which, being a field, is everything except $0$.

Comment: Well, thank you. I confound. $\mathbb F_{16}$ is the field, which can be constructed by factorizing $\mathbb F_2 [X]$ with an irreducible polynomial from $\mathbb F_2 [X]$ of degree 4.

Answer (score 2):

A primitive root of a finite field is a generator of its multiplicative group.

$\alpha$ has order $15$ and so $\beta=\alpha^3$ has order $5$. This is true in any group.

Now, $\beta$ is neither in $\mathbb F_2$ nor in $\mathbb F_4$ because it is not a root of $X^3-1$. Therefore, the smallest field that contains $\beta$ is $\mathbb F_{16}$ and so its degree over $\mathbb F_2$ is $4$.

Indeed, since $x^5-1$ factors as $(x + 1) (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) \bmod 2$, the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: Why you chose the polynomial $X^3-1$ ?
If $\beta$ would be a root, then $\alpha^9=1$, but what does that give me? Is it possible, that you mean the polynomial $X^5-1$?

Comment: @MyrkulsJayKay, every nonzero element of $\mathbb F_4$ is a root of $X^3-1$.